# Problemas com Security Level Trust (Servidor Locaweb)

Tags: c#, iis

Ola, estou tendo o seguinte mensagem de erro abaixo:

---

### This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using  from an inherited configuration file.

Isso é referente ao nivel de segurança do servidor, mas a questão é que já alterei o web.config de varias formas, para colocar uma aplicação MVC4 no ar em servidor da locaweb windows 2012 IIS7 aparentemente é uma aplicação simples usando coisas DLLs básicas do Entity Framework com banco de dados MySQL.

Questionei o suporte e recebi a seguinte resposta

> As configurações entre emuladores de servidores locais, servidores de
>   provedores de hospedagem, são na imensa maioria das vezes, diferentes
>   entre si.  Somente este procedimento [] não é
>   o suficiente para alterar o Security Level de uma aplicação. Para que
>   você possa resolver corretamente problemas de Security Level, deve: 
>   Para DLL’s de terceiros:  • Verificar com o fabricante a possibilidade
>   de trabalhar com a DLL em Security Level configurado no servidor de
>   sua hospedagem;  Para DLL’s próprias:  • Analisar os scripts e
>   verificar se a execução dos mesmos é permitida no Security Level
>   configurado no servidor de sua hospedagem;  Para aplicações oriundas
>   de outros provedores:  • Verificar, antecipadamente, se as DLL’s
>   existentes na aplicação são compatíveis com Security Level de seu
>   plano de hospedagem;  • O ideal é que tal verificação seja feita antes
>   de disponibilizar sua aplicação em modo de “produção” em nossos
>   servidores.

1 - O que mais posso fazer para poder sanar isso ?
2 - Minha aplicação foi compilada em 4.5 e pelo que percebi la no servidor é 4.0

ainda não tive tempo de compilar minha aplicação MVC em 4.0 mas sera que daria certo ?

Levantei essa questão por que realmente esta me dando dor de cabeça, e queria saber se alguém já passou por esse tipo de problema com Hospedagens tal.

Att
Rodrigo

Comment: Eu diria pra você nem perder tempo com a Locaweb. Que eu saiba, a compatibilidade deles com o ASP.NET MVC é bem limitada, e as DLLs do MySQL bem antigas.

Comment: Qual serviço de hospedagem seria melhor ? tipo para aplicações MVC tals ? tem alguma dica ?

Comment: Comprei uma nuvem na UolHost esses dias. Achei bem em conta, mas depende da aplicação. A Azure também está com preços bem bons.